# order of growth of the worst case running time

Tags: big-o

I have this question as follows

```
int sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i*i<N; i++)
  for(int j=0; j*j<4*N; j++)
   for(int k=0; k<N*N; k++)
    sum++;
```

How to find the order of growth of the worst case running time of the above question.Please explain step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming N is your parameter

for(int i = 0; i*i < N; i++) - 
O(sqrt(N))

for(int j=0; j*j<4*N; j++) - 
O(sqrt(N))

for(int k=0; k < N*N; k++) - 
O(n^2)

Inside of the last loop - constant.

So, each loop is inside the previous, you multiply it, so it's O(n^3)

Comment: This is correct and precise. Simply because (i*i <N) = i <sqrt(N).